# Looking for a SQL Server 2000 fix to a problem fixed in 2005

Tags: sql-server

I have been having fits with my application that uses SQL Server and I finally found a description of the problem as a bug fix for SQL Server 2005.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/912732

The only problem is, my database server is SQL Server 2000. Is there any way to find out if SQL Server 2000 has an equivalent patch?

From the MS KB article

> 1. You open a connection and start a Transact-SQL transaction by using the "System.Data.SqlClient" namespace.
> 2. You close the connection without completing the Transact-SQL transaction.
> 3. You request another connection and receive the previous connection from the connection pool.
> 4. You start a new transaction by using the SqlConnection.BeginTransaction method.

I have strong reasons to believe "2" is happening in another application using another database on the same server. Then "3" happens when my app grabs a connection from the pool that was screwed up by another application.

I am not able to upgrade to 2005 due to non-technical constraints, but if I can find a patch to fix this issue in SQL Server 2000, I can have it applied.

Has anyone found a fix in 2000?

Answer (score 1):

From what I'm seeing in the KB article, that fix applies to the .NET 2.0 framework and not SQL 2005 specifically.  It also doesn't have one of those epic sounding warning "only apply this if you are experiencing these symptoms".

If you have a test environment I would apply the patch to update the .NET framework and see if it fixes your problem.